# Override module's model with another Magento 2 module

Tags: magento2, overrides

I tried to override a custom module model with creating a new module, i got class not found error

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="V1_M1" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="V2_M2"/>
    </sequence>
</module>    
</config>
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="V2\M2\Model\Quote\Email\Sender\QuoteProposalSender" type="V1\M1\Model\Quote\Email\Sender\QuoteProposalSender" />
</config>
```

**class Model/Quote/Email/Sender/QuoteProposalSender.php**

```
namespace V1\M1\Model\Quote\Email\Sender;


class QuoteProposalSender extends \V2\M2\Model\Quote\Email\Sender\QuoteProposalSender
 {


public function checkAndSend(
    \V2\M2\Model\Quote $quote,$attachments = null) {
    return $this->traitCheckAndSend($quote, $attachments);
}


}
```

When executing the command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

I got this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'V2\M2\Model\Quote\Email\Sender\QuoteProposalSender' not found in /app/code/V1/M1/Model/Quote/Email/Sender/QuoteProposalSender.php on line 14
```

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Comment: Check the spelling of folder.

Comment: The module works on server but not on localhost, i think there's issue related to V2_M2 module